# Kudan Unity: After Marker tracking detects cannot switch to Markerless properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kudan

In the Kudan samples for Unity (testing on Android) I'm finding that once the 'Marker' tracking finds its target if I try to switch to 'Markerless' the ArrowPlace script doesn't update the arrow any more (its just stuck in the center of the screen) and then when the markerless is placed its not orientated correctly. I am having a real problem working out what I need to do when 'changeTrackingMethod' happens so that Markerless will work correctly after 'Marker' has alread detected. Any ideas?

Comment: Kudan is actually working to fix this very issue. In the meantime, I do happen to know that when the app loses focus and then regains focus (ie, you go to the home screen and then back into the app), it does reset the tracker and seemingly fixes the markerless tracking bug. So you might be able to reset it in some way after you change the tracking method.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I tried calling OnApplicationPause and OnApplicationFocus both before and after _currentTrackingMethod.StartTracking(); in kudanTracker ChangeTrackingMethod, but sadly no difference (and actually going in and out of the app made no difference for me either). The Markerless placement object shows but doesn't move- like I describe above :(

Comment: @DisturbedNeo I'm still having this problem with Unity version 1.3 actually- any update on if this is fixed and if so how to do what I need (i.e. switch between modes and or stop arbiTracking one scene and then start arbitracking again in a new scene- so it shows the arrowplace marker again)

Comment: OK I have made some progress on this. What I needed to do was DeInitialize Kudan and its native plugin altogether when switching scenes and re-initialize it again, which is not ideal. Is The Unity Android plugin missing some call to ArbiTracking stop and its followup call to set arbitrack_state = ARBITRACK_STATE.ARBI_PLACEMENT; or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't switch markerless to marker so i don't know this issue. But for orientation issue , if the orientation move when you move your smartphone , I have sometimes the same thing, and currently to stop have this issue, I restart my phone.

Comment: Ouch! I havent encountered that so far- what devices are you testing on? Re the issue, I wonder if maybe when a 'Marker' is found if perhaps the underlying SDK stops the gyro for the arbi tracking and it doesn't get switched on again or something... Maybe this will be fixed with the next update- not sure if the Unity version is using the same iOS/Android code as the latest iOS/Android SDKs (1.3)

Comment: I used an htc one m7, you can watch this video where all work quite well and no issue with rotating: [link](https://youtu.be/_7zctFw-O0Y)